# Using sed to delete everything between and including <?php ?> on the first line of code

Tags: php, linux, sed

My server was recently hacked and php code injected and at the first line of every php file there is something like

```
<?php $jybcqmhk = 'x24- x24*<!~!    x24/%t2w/ //truncated code  ?><?php
```

The code itself is slightly different on each file but usually after the first ?> my actual code starts.

Is there a way using something like SED where I can remove everything on the first line between  and leave the rest.

I've tried a few things but ended up with either having an extra php opening tag or accidentally deleting code on the line after the php closing tag.

For example, this worked where the code started with a php opening tag, but breaks for anything else.

```
find ./ -iname '*.php' -exec sed -i '1 s/^.*$/<?php/g' {} \;
```

Comment: Did you patch the original hole they got through yet? Because removing those lines without fixing the vulnerability is kinda pointless.

Comment: You'd be better rebuilding the whole site and trying to figure out how they got in

Comment: I know where the security hole is, but I want to clean the files first before moving my sites to a new host.

Comment: If you can't precisely define what `there is something like` is then I would not recommend running a script to remove `something like` anything from your files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this could help :

```
find ./ -iname '*.php' -exec sed -i '1 s/<?php/\n&/2;s/<?php.*\n//' {} \;
```

The sed command operates 2 substitutions : the first one isolates the first `<?php ?>`command in a new line, the second one deletes it.

Comment: It will not work if the ternary operator is used (for example):  `sed '1 s/<?php[^?]*?>//' <<< '<?php $a = 1 ? 2 : 3; ?>'` <-- does not work

Comment: Thanks for your comment @hek2mgl, i updated my answer

Comment: Thanks I will give that a try :-)

Comment: Perfect, did exactly what I needed, thank very much :-)